# Linking with TCMalloc but the CRT malloc always called

Tags: windows, tcmalloc

I would like to experiment a bit with TCMalloc on Windows. I have built the VisualStudio solution which is part of the gperftools package I downloaded. But when I run any of the test apps which also came with the download, say tcmalloc_minimal_unittest.exe, all the memory allocation calls go to the standard malloc. Has anybody seen this already and knows what I should do? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I answer my own question. This may be useful to someone else. I was seeing on the VS debugger that the CRT malloc was invoked, but looking at the assembler code I see that the beginning of the function is patched, showing a jump to Perftools_malloc. So, apparently, instead of presenting a different API, TCMalloc hooks into regular calls to the CRT.